# Changing Link Color and DIV text

Tags: colors, hyperlink, tags

Please see the following JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MWcAF/56/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=answer]').not('#answer').hide();
    $('[class^="question"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
        $('[id^=answer]').hide();
        $('#answer' + numb).show();
        var plinks = $('div.plink a');
        plinks.removeClass('active');
        var alink = $(this);
        alink.addClass('active');
        $('#answer' + numb).show();

    });

});
```

Primarily, this script does what I want it to do. When I click Question 1, Answer 1 is displayed. When I click Question 2, Answer 2 is displayed, and so on.

My issue is, if I click any of the questions two times in a row, the answer disappears until I click a different question. So it's like this:

1. Click Q1
2. A1 appears
3. Click Q1 again
4. A1 disappears
5. Click Q1 again
6. A1 is still gone
7. Click Q2
8. A2 appears
9. Click Q1
10. A1 appears

Anyone know how I can get the answer to stay if the question is clicked more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code is problematic:

```
var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
```

`this.className` has a value of "question1 active" when the clicked question was already the active question, so `numb` would get the value "1 active"

There are two approaches to fixing this:

1. remove the "active" class before computing the value of numb
2. use regular expressions:
   `var myRe = /question(\d)/g; 
   var myArray = myRe.exec(this.className); 
   var numb = myArray[1];`

Comment: Can you suggest a fix? I tried adding a line:

var numb = this?className.replace('active', '')

But that didn't work to clear the "active" class.

Comment: Your second approach worked for me! Much appreciated! http://jsfiddle.net/MWcAF/68/